# Print driver host 32bit applications has stopped working

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer

I get an error message : Print driver host 32bit applications has stopped working.
I work with Server 2008 R2
I stopped the Print Spooler Service and deleted all files in this folder : %WINDIR%\system32\spool\printers.
After that I started the Print Spooler Service.
It does not help, still shows an error message.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a faulty x86 print driver. Please check the error log if you can see a .dll in reference, to help to find the problematic driver.

After that update the driver it or remove it from your server to prevent it's usage.

You can enable too print isolation, thus only the bugged driver will stop working if the driver support to be isolated. That will help the health of your server.

> Printer driver isolation improves the reliability of the Windows print
>   service, by enabling printer drivers to run in processes that are
>   separate from the process in which the print spooler runs.